# Can I update my zonefile's MX record to use an SES endpoint without disturbing my EC2 instance's ability to send mail?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, amazon-web-services, mx-record

I have a zonefile with an MX record and an A record that both point to the same server. This server receives orders and then sends e-mail using sendmail to a pre-configured e-mail address.

I want to experiment with receiving e-mail now, and it seems I need to change my MX record to an SES endpoint to get SES to receive e-mail.

Now, my zonefile is configured to have the EC2 instance for the MX record, but the EC2 instance doesn't receive any e-mail, only sends mail.

If I update the MX record to an SES endpoint, this this going to interfere with the EC2 instance's ability to send outgoing mail?

Answer (score 3):

From a pure SMTP standpoint, that would be OK. However, at the very least you should add proper SPF records and optimally DKIM as well to make it less likely  your mail is classified as spam.